# Replace text in .so file using Vim

Tags: linux, vim, hex, .so

My need is to replace all cases of a certain text in a .so file.

I use vim to open the file and then use `:%!xxd` to convert it to a readable format, like in sample output below:

```
000001a0: f217 4dce 4321 4118 3940 1326 9a3a 62f6  ..M.C!A.9@.&.:b.                                                                                                         
000001b0: 2fde ecdd 0000 0000 0300 0000 a800 0000  /...............                                                                                                         
000001c0: 0100 0000 0600 0000 88c2 2001 0007 4109  .......... ...A.                                                                                                         
000001d0: a800 0000 ac00 0000 ae00 0000 4245 d5ec  ............BE..                                                                                                         
000001e0: bae3 927c 7092 55aa 694a b111 d871 581c  ...|p.U.iJ...qX.                                                                                                         
000001f0: b98d f10e ebd3 ef0e 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

My problem is that with this structure, I cannot search over line breaks, making my mission to replace text inachievable by going over search/replace results.

Is there a way to make vim show only the hex values, and without line breaks?

Any other solution that will allow text replacement over line breaks (so it could be done in one shot), is welcome as well.

Thank you!

Comment: you can make it less bad by telling xxd to do more than 16 bytes per line, and group them all together with no spaces: `:%!xxd -c 60 -g 60`

Comment: Thanks, that can help for sure. In order to reverse it once finished, shall ```:%!xxd -r -c 60 -g 60```  be valid? It performs a reversing without errors, but I'm not sure if it does it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that a text editor will save binary files correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sed multi-line search](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Text-search-across-multiple-lines.html) in combination with [hex escape notation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Escapes.html#Escapes) to search and replace any hex patter in any file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit new to linux. Could you share an example of how you'll use it? Thanks (: